# Append items to Simple Adapter dynamically

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have a very simple question. I'm working on an Android application where I make use of Simple Adapter for ListView. Now I need to append items to this ListView dynamically. I know it is possible to do so in case of Array Adapters.

It is done as follows:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is there any equivalent for the same in case of Simple Adapters? I couldn't find much relevant links regarding this on the net.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think not, but you always can create a new `SimpleAdapter` and call `setAdapter` again with the new adapter.

If you are going to add/remove elements you, probably, need some other adapter not a `SimpleAdapter`. Because they say in the docs that SimpleAdapter is 'An easy adapter to map **static data** to views defined in an XML file'

Comment: Actually, I don't think that you even need to create a new SimpleAdapter in this case - just call setAdapter after the change